# In TypeScript how can I declare class method synonym?

Tags: typescript

I want to define class method which is supposed to do the same as other class method and return the same value. Something like that:

```ts
class Thing {
    _description : string
    description( new_desc : string ) : Thing {
        this._description = new_desc
        return this
    }

    /** And here I want to define method which is doing absolutely the same and
        returning the same value, but targeting API users that are lazy to type.*/
    desc( ? ) {
        ?
    }
}
```

In plain **JavaScript** I would do it like this:

```js
class Thing {
    _description
    description( new_desc ) {
        this._description = new_desc
        return this
    }

    desc() {
        return this.description.apply( this, arguments )
    }
}
```

But it obviously breaks all the types inference and safety.

How can I do it in **TypeScript** to ensure type-safety?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with [index access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) and the [Parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) utility type ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqAWBLAdgc2gbwFDV9ADgE6IBuYALgKbQD6AJpRMMfuYgPbLQC80ARHwDcOPAyYs2nABTRklAO71GwAFzQI5YmmgBKTCLx5ySCADol4xKw5decxWOAHD0QpXIBXQl2OIIzgF8sZ0cpU3CwQlQINQAFSLAAW3dKQggAHgQUVABtPkcJGz4AXQA%20PWwXPDdPb2hfMwKrSWRTMHx8EABPGQaAGmhI6N1ArCDg4E4NesZyHlkFOCQ0KR1hKg1TJutpPg3yPjWsfa3lKT3Zw-XZ06YpAFY9AHon6FTCdkIgA)):

```
class Thing {
    private _description = "";
    description( new_desc: string ) {
        this._description = new_desc
        return this
    }

    desc(...args: Parameters<Thing["description"]>) {
        return this.description.apply( this, args )
    }
}


const test = new Thing();
test.description("test");
test.desc("test");
test.desc(5) // error
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just:

```
desc( new_desc : string ) : Thing {
     return this.description(new_desc);
}
```

Comment: `Thing.description()` might get rewritten to take additional arguments what will render `Thing.desc()` invalid.

Comment: Ok, in that case please add this information to the description, 'cause it is important to mention.